# How can I rebind keyboard keys in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, bash

I need a custom keyboard shortcut for back slash <kbd>\</kbd>.

I have created `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and put this in it:

```
{
    "@ö" = ("insertText:", "\\");
}
```

It is supposed to trigger back slash when pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>ö</kbd> 
*(Yes, I have an "ö" character on my keyboard).*

When trying to `source` the file, I get this error:

```
-bash: DefaultKeyBinding.dict: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: DefaultKeyBinding.dict: line 2: `    "@ö" = ("insertText:", "\\");'
```

What's wrong with the syntax? Is there a better way?

Comment: From a brief web search for "DefaultKeyBinding.dict", according to http://xahlee.info/kbd/osx_keybinding.html: "only application that [use] Cocoa text system will support this." This is not a shell file, and will not work when 'source'ed via bash.

Comment: @mtklr You're probably right. It's strange because a number of answers on StackExchange recommended this method for creating custom key bindings in OS X – that's why I got involved with it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Ö</kbd> -> <kbd>\</kbd> just remap the key combo with Karabiner. The shortcut you need isn't pre-defined so you have to write your own:

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
5. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
6. Enter the customized keycode

   Example 1 (<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>Ö</kbd> -> <kbd>\</kbd>):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
         <name>Command-Ö to Backslash</name>
         <appendix>(Change Command-Ö to \)</appendix>
         <identifier>remap.command_ö_to_backslash</identifier>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::GERMAN_O_UMLAUT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_COMMAND, KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```

   Example 2 (<kbd>cmd_R</kbd><kbd>Ö</kbd> -> <kbd>\</kbd> cmd_R is the right command key only, <kbd>cmd_L</kbd><kbd>Ö</kbd> doesn't have an output!):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
         <name>Command_R-Ö to Backslash</name>
         <appendix>(Change Command_R-Ö to \)</appendix>
         <identifier>remap.command_r_ö_to_backslash</identifier>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::GERMAN_O_UMLAUT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```

   Example 3 (<kbd>cmd_R</kbd> -> <kbd>\</kbd> you can't use the right command key for any other purpose then):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
         <name>Command_R to Backslash</name>
         <appendix>(Change Command_R to \)</appendix>
         <identifier>remap.command_r_to_backslash</identifier>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```

   Example 4 (<kbd>cmd_R</kbd> -> <kbd>\</kbd> similar to example 3 but you can use the right command key as normal command key-> hitting <kbd>cmd_R</kbd> yields \ but <kbd>cmd_R</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> saves files):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
         <name>When you type Command_R only, send Backslash</name>
         <appendix>(Change Command_R lazy to \)</appendix>
         <identifier>remap.command_r_lazy_to_backslash</identifier>
         <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::VK_LAZY_COMMAND_R, KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```
7. Save the file
8. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
9. Hit the ReloadXML button
10. Enable the remapping. It should be listed at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks very much for this! I especially found it powerful to bind `cmd_R` per your suggestion.

Comment: @Winterflags By accident I made a forward_slash instead of a back_slash in all of the appendix sections. I amended that. It's only a cosmetic problem though.

Comment: This stopped working for me – I haven't changed the XML and it worked in the past. Just curious if there's some obvious reason for it not working (e.g. the syntax changed)?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Karabiner ?

> A powerful and stable keyboard customizer for OS X.
>
> - You can easily customize from prepared settings.
> - You can also add your own settings by XML.

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Comment: Note that Karabiner doesn't work on macOS Sierra, and the authors have indicated that substantial changes will be necessary before it will work on that OS.

Comment: @Peter "answered Dec 21 '15" - Sierra September 16

Comment: Thanks MrMojoRinsin - I've always wondered what these "date" things were.  Seriously though, I was pointing this out so that anyone today (or in the near future) who might stumble across this post would know that your answer doesn't apply for macOS Sierra (yet).

Answer (score 1):

From a brief web search for `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`, according to [this page](http://xahlee.info/kbd/osx_keybinding.html):

> Only application that [use] Cocoa text system will support this.

This is not a shell file, and will not work when 'source'ed via bash.

<sup>Source: [@mtklr comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219629/how-can-i-rebind-keyboard-keys-in-os-x#comment265978_219629).</sup>