# Remap SHIFT + SPACE to underscore?

Tags: keybindings

I'd like to remap the shift key (⇧) + space (␣) to underscore (`_`)

I'd prefer to not have to install any third party tools if possible.

Similar question for [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/419736/remapping-shift-space-to-an-underscore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a third party tool, you will face a similar problem as the OP in this question ([DefaultKeyBinding.dict: Syntax error near unexpected token](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219629/defaultkeybinding-dict-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token)) that only applications which use the Cocoa text system will support this.

Additionally it appears that the <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> key can't be properly used as modifier key if <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>some key</kbd> doesn't have another representation than an unmodified <kbd>some key</kbd> - and <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> doesn't have one.

You may either create a *DefaultKeyBinding.dict* or install *Karabiner* and configure a custom keycode.

**DefaultKeyBinding.dict** (only applications which use the Cocoa text system will support this)

Open Terminal and enter:

```
mkdir ~/Library/KeyBindings
touch ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```

Use `nano ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` to add (using another shortcut like <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>ctrl ^</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> here):

```
{
    "@^ " = ("insertText:", "_");
}
```

to output an underscore.

**Karabiner** (all apps should support this)

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
5. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
6. Enter the customized keycode

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
           <name>Shift Space to Underscore</name>
           <appendix>(Change Shift-space to _)</appendix>
           <identifier>remap.shiftspace2underscore</identifier>
           <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SPACE, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_SHIFT, KeyCode::MINUS, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_SHIFT,</autogen>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```
7. Save the file
8. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
9. Hit the ReloadXML button
10. Enable the remapping. It should be listed at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

The Karabiner code in the 2015 response is now outdated, as Karabiner now uses JSON instead of XML. You can add a custom complex modification by creating a file called ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/my_modification.json and use the following JSON code. Then open the karabinder-Elements app, navigate to "Complex Modifications", and enable the rules you have just added.

```
    {
        "title": "Underscore mapping",
        "rules": [
            {
                "manipulators": [
                    {
                        "description": "Change left_shift+space to underscore (_).",
                        "from": {
                            "key_code": "spacebar",
                            "modifiers": {
                                "mandatory" : [
                                    "left_shift"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "to": [
                            {
                                "key_code": "hyphen",
                                "modifiers": [
                                    "left_shift"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "type": "basic"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "manipulators": [
                    {
                        "description": "Change right_shift+space to underscore (_).",
                        "from": {
                            "key_code": "spacebar",
                            "modifiers": {
                                "mandatory" : [
                                    "right_shift"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "to": [
                            {
                                "key_code": "hyphen",
                                "modifiers": [
                                    "left_shift"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "type": "basic"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```